# Add thread into thread array

Tags: c#

Take a look at my code.

```
Thread[] connect_thread;
public void thread_runned()
{
    connect_thread = new Thread[dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count];
    for (int index = 0; index < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; index++)
    {
        connect_thread[index] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(connect));
        connect_thread[index].Start();
    }
}
public void connect()
{
   //performance code here
}
public void ButtonClick1()
{
    //User select rows 0-4
    thread_runned();
}

public void ButtonClick2()
{
    //User select rows 5-9
    thread_runned();
}
```

According to the code above, when I run it, and click on `ButtonClick1` and `ButtonClick2`, it returns two different `connect_thread`s (see this debug for more detail.)

```
//Debug when ButtonClick1 is running
connect_thread = array(
    [0] = System.Threading.Thread
    [1] = System.Threading.Thread
    [2] = System.Threading.Thread
    [3] = System.Threading.Thread
)

//Debug when ButtonClick2 is running
connect_thread = Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

Now, I want to add a new thread item into this thread array, but the indeces must continue like the old thread items (i.e, the next indeces will be `[4]`, `[5]`, `[6]`, etc.)

I'm not worrying about this error:

```
//Debug when ButtonClick2 is running
connect_thread = Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

because I can create a list of threads using `dataGridView1.Rows.Count`, and it will work fine. However, I'm looking to do it the other way other because when the user adds more data into `dataGridView`, the index will be wrong again.

How can I append new threads to the end of my thread array while preserving indeces?

Comment: Use List<Thread> instead of Thread[] array.

Comment: So is your question "How to add an item to a list?"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to replace your array with list like below:

```
List<Thread> connect_thread = new List<Thread>()
public void thread_runned()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; index++)
    {
        connect_thread.add(new Thread(new ThreadStart(connect)));
        connect_thread[connect_thread.Count-1].Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have an array with a defined size, it is not a good pratice define a new size for an array. Instead it, you could use a `List<Thread>` and add how many threads you need, for sample:

```
List<Thread> connect_threads;

public void thread_runned()
{
    int total =  dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;

    // define the array
    connect_threads = new List<Thread>();   

    // define threads all threads on the list
    for (int index = 0; index < total; index++)
        connect_threads.Add(new Thread(new ThreadStart(connect)));

    // start all threads on the list
    foreach(var thread in connect_threads)
        thread.Start();

    // if you want to wait all the threads on the list to finish
    foreach(var thread in connect_threads)
        thread.Join();              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of argument, use [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
    Int32 _ActiveThreadCount = 0;

    delegate void SetTextCallback(String text);

    public Int32 ActiveThreadCount
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _ActiveThreadCount; 
        }
        set 
        {
            _ActiveThreadCount = value;
            SetText(value.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void OnThreadCallback(Object state)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ActiveThreadCount--;
    }

    private void SetText(String text)
    {
        if (label2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback callback = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(callback, text);
        }
        else
        {
            this.label2.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Add threads using

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    new System.Threading.WaitCallback(OnThreadCallback), null);
ActiveThreadCount++;
```

As for the rest, I'm not really sure what exactly the question is here.